# How to set the variable value to the resource selectors?

Tags: java, aem, sightly

I need to set the selector using data-sly-resource.
It works if I set the selector name directly.
But I need to pass the selector name which is saved in variable.
How to set the value of "selector" variable ("settings1" or "settings2") to the selectors of data-sly-resource?

```
<template data-sly-template.edit="${ @ settings }">
        <div data-sly-test.selector="${settings == 'data' ? 'settings1' : 'settings2'}">
            <div data-sly-resource="${ @path='home', resourceType='/aem/test/components/component', selectors='${selector}' }"></div>
        </div>
</template>
```

This code doesn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass HTL variables directly to the expression options:

`data-sly-resource="${ @path='home', resourceType='/aem/test/components/component', selectors=selector }"`

BTW, instead of `data-sly-test` you could use [`data-sly-set`](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#2212-set) to assign the value for `selector`.